# How to get an object from RuntimePropertyInfo?

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm trying to find all properties containing an object that implelents an interface, and execute a method on the object. This is the code I have so far:

```
foreach (var propertyInfo in this.GetType().GetProperties()
    .Where(xx => xx.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(SearchMeAttribute), false).Any()))
{
    if (propertyInfo.PropertyType.GetInterfaces().Any(xx => xx == typeof(IAmSearchable)))
    {
        // the following doesn't work, though I hoped it would
        return ((IAmSearchable)propertyInfo).SearchMeLikeYouKnowIAmGuilty(term);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I get the error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo' to type 'ConfigurationServices.ViewModels.IAmSearchable'.

How can I get the actual object, rather than the `RuntimePropertyInfo`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to get the value from the property with the [`GetValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getvalue.aspx) method:

```
object value = propertyInfo.GetValue(this, null);
```

The `this` is the "target" of the property, and the `null` indicates that you're expecting just a parameterless property, not an indexer.

Comment: Thank you!  your explanation made it "click" for me.